configuracion de archivo astro.config para dev y para build
necesitó que astro tenga una ruta cuando se hace el npm run build y otra cuando se hace el npm run dev , por ahora con la información que tengo sé que hay que hacer unas configuraciones en el archivo astro.config.ms, pero los intentos por ahora no dan fruto.
ya que cuando hago el npm run build y lo subo a github pages no carga el css,y si se ve en local al hacer npm run dev
este es el código que tengo:
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';


export default defineConfig({
  /* asi funciona pero es la misma ruta para dev y build
  site: 'https://url',
  base: 'carpeta_a_usar',*/
  server: {
   host: true,
   devOptions: {
    site: 'https://url',
    base: 'carpeta_base',
   },
   buildOptions: {
    site: 'https://url',
    base: '',
   },
 },
});


ya encontré una solución y es la siguiente:
1 - Creamos un archivo astro.config.build.mjs en este archivo se harán las configuraciones para cuando se haga npm run build
2 - Modificamos el archivo package.json en la línea que dice
"build": "astro build",

lo remplazamos por:
"build": "astro build --config astro.config.build.mjs",

esto hará que cada vez que se ejecute npm run build se configure con el nuevo archivo creado y dejando el comando npm run dev ejecutándose con el archivo por defecto astro.config.mjs
